# Python Pandas: categorize/bin by numeric groupings with zero values

Tags: python, pandas, grouping, nan, categories

I am not sure, if this is the most efficient way, but I am working to group customer spend into bins/buckets.

This is the df I am working on:

```
df.head()

Best_ID_S| Dollar
abc2464    0.00 
fdhg357    672.00  
hjg5235    250.00 
mjhur57    199.00 
erew3452   116.25
```

This is my code:

```
bins = [0,250,500,750,1000,1500,2000,2500,3000,3500,4000,4500,5000,5500,6000,6500,7000,8000,1000000000000]
#I didn't know how to create 8000+ so I just added a crazy number in the end, it works

group_names = ['0-250','251-500','501-749','750-999','1000-1499','1500-1999','2000-2499','2500-2999','3000-3499','3500-3999','4000-4499','4500-4999','5000-5499','5500-5999','6000-6499','6500-6999','7000-7499','8000+']

categories = pd.cut(df_2014['Dollar'], bins, labels=group_names)
df['Category'] = pd.cut(df['Dollar'], bins, labels=group_names)
df['Buckets'] = pd.cut(df['Dollar'], bins)
```

This is what I get, when I do df.head():

```
Best_ID_S| Dollar | Category |  Buckets
abc2464    0.00     NaN
fdhg357    672.00   501-749        (500, 750]
hjg5235    250.00   0-250          (0, 250]
mjhur57    199.00   0-250          (0, 250]
erew3452   116.25   0-250          (0, 250]
```

Where Dollar Value is 0, I need it to be the bucket 0-250. But I am getting NaN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default value of `right` parameter is true. Mathematically `(` indicate excluding the left one, so that needs to be `[` to include the value in the left. So change the pd.cut to

```
df['Category'] = pd.cut(df['Dollar'], bins, labels=group_names,right=False)
df['Buckets'] = pd.cut(df['Dollar'], bins,right=False)
```

```
 Best_ID_S|  Dollar Category     Buckets
0    abc2464    0.00    0-250    [0, 250)
1    fdhg357  672.00  501-749  [500, 750)
2    hjg5235  250.00  251-500  [250, 500)
3    mjhur57  199.00    0-250    [0, 250)
4   erew3452  116.25    0-250    [0, 250)
```

Incase of making it left inclusive you can also set `include_lowest`to `True` by keeping the right parameter `True`.

Answer (score 1):

To create a bin above 8000, you can use the last bin as np.inf

```
bins = [0,250,500,750,1000,1500,2000,2500,3000,3500,4000,4500,5000,5500,6000,6500,7000,8000,np.inf]
```

For including the lower bound, you can use parameter include_lowest = True

```
df['Category'] = pd.cut(df['Dollar'], bins, labels=group_names, include_lowest=True)
df['Buckets'] = pd.cut(df['Dollar'], bins, include_lowest=True)
```

You get

```
    Best_ID_S   Dollar  Category    Buckets
0   abc2464     0.00    0-250   [0, 250]
1   fdhg357     672.00  501-749 (500, 750]
2   hjg5235     250.00  0-250   [0, 250]
3   mjhur57     199.00  0-250   [0, 250]
4   erew3452    116.25  0-250   [0, 250]
```

Comment: I did add that at the end hahaha

Comment: Oh ok, I saw that now:)

Comment: The reason I din't add the ouput is because I got `df.loc[0,'Buckets']` -   `(-0.001, 250.0]` . Any idea why?

Comment: Hmmm, I wonder. I am getting the desired output. May be try with include_lowest.